# Scroll down animation js

Tags: javascript

I built a kind of chat in JS and then I wanted that when I got new message the chat automatically scrolled down (with animation...). Everything worked beautifully, but after the animation stopped the user couldn't scroll by himself; the chat automatically scrolled to the end.

So this is the code :

```
<!-- language:lang-js -->

var height = 1;
window.setInterval(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('chat');
    elem.scrollTop = height;
    if (elem.scrollheight < height) {
        clearInterval(this);
    }
    height += 2;
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) function expects a number. Using that should make it work correctly. You also have many syntax errors.

```
var intervalReference = window.setInterval(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('chat');
    elem.scrollTop = height;
    if (elem.scrollHeight < height) {
        clearInterval(intervalReference);
    }
    height += 2;
}, 50);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yg5zQ/2/  i never worked with this website before so it dont work (i trying to fixed it ...)

Comment: @asafg8 you still have `scrollHeight` wrong, notice the capital `H`, here it is working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yg5zQ/5/), although, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yg5zQ/7/) is probably what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

you should make a var holding the interval like this :

```
var height = 1;
var interval = window.setInterval( animate, 50 );

function animate() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('chat');
    elem.scrollTop = height;
    if (elem.scrollHeight < height) {
        clearInterval( interval );
    }
    height += 2;
}
```

this should work fine

Comment: setInterval(animate(), 50) --> setInterval(animate, 50).